# document.getElementById() returns null, null all the time?

Tags: javascript, null, getelementbyid

There are many answers to those questions but I still cannot resolve it. Sorry if that is so obvious. 
When I am using document.getElementById() all the time I get null. Any ideas???

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Widget Text Finder</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
</head>

<body id="main-body">

    <div id="dp-container">
        <iframe id="dir-page" scrolling="no" src="inside.html"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div id="widget-container">
        <iframe id="widget-page" scrolling="no" src="widget.html"></iframe>
    </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

widget.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Widget</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
</head>

<body id="widget-body">

    <img id="pic" src="img/wi01.PNG" alt="trans_level_1">

    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

inside.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>inside</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
</head>

<body id="body-inside">
    <div>
        <form>
            <input id="text" value="hello" type="text" name="txt-direction">
        </form>

        <img id="pic" src="https://www.trzcacak.rs/myfile/full/57-573508_file-jupiter-symbol-svg-jupiter-astrological-sign.png" alt="direct-pic">
    </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

main.js

```
window.onload = function() {
    var a = document.getElementById("pic");
    var b = document.getElementById("text");

    a.addEventListener("click", function() { b.value = "test" });

}
```

Here what I get from Chrome Developer tools
[image]

I get always null when I am using document.getElementById. Please help!

Comment: index.html does not have elements with either of those id's - and widget.html has no element with id=text ... document.getElementById does not "look" inside iframes

Comment: Only `inside.html` has both elements. What happens if you put the javascript directly inside the `<script></script>` tag instead of loading a file?

Answer (score 2):

The first `index.html` file does not have an `id="pic"` element, so that one will fail.

The second `widget.html` file does not have an `id="text"` element, so there is nothing to click

The third `inside.html` file seems to work fine (I had to put the javascript directly in the page for this example, but when I tested it locally with a `main.js` file it also worked as expected.

Each html page should have its own js file, depending on what you are trying to accomplish? The same one will not work for all of your examples.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>inside</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
</head>

<body id="body-inside">
    <div>
        <form>
            <input id="text" value="hello" type="text" name="txt-direction">
        </form>

        <img id="pic" src="https://www.trzcacak.rs/myfile/full/57-573508_file-jupiter-symbol-svg-jupiter-astrological-sign.png" alt="direct-pic">
    </div>
    <script>
      window.onload = function() {
        var a = document.getElementById("pic");
        var b = document.getElementById("text");

        console.log(a, b);

        a.addEventListener("click", function() { b.value = "test" });
    }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. That thought me a lot. The thing that I want to accomplish is to access an iFrame document trough the main page and use all the features that are available under the window and document class. Your answer shows me a good direction. FYI: The thing that I want is here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-mNp3-UX9Qc

Answer (score -6):

Wait for the Dom content to load.

```
 window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    var a = document.getElementById("pic");
    var b = document.getElementById("text");
    a.addEventListener("click", function() { b.value = "test" }); }
});
```

Comment: OP wouldn't even need to wait for window.load event - if only he had the id's he was looking for

Comment: The script is at the end of the HTML, so the DOM is loaded.

Comment: As @Barmar said, the script is being reference before the end of `</body>` which is the correct location for `onload`

Comment: Sorry, this is often the fix to when I have this issue

Comment: That's true, it's often the fix when you have the script at the beginning and don't use `window.onload`.